# Exact Likelihood ratio statistic for discrete distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, likelihood-ratio, discrete-distributions

Suppose that the random variables in a sample $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ are iid with values in $[0,1]$, and that an investigator knows that the underlying probability density $f_Y(y)$ has the form

$f_Y(y)=f_Y(y, a, b) \equiv\left\{\begin{array}{rll}a & \text { for } & 0 \leq y<1 \\ b & \text { for } & 1 \leq y<2 \\ 1-a-b & \text { for } & 2<y \leq 3\end{array}\right.$

for some $a, b>0, a+b<1$, but thinks that $a=2 b$.

(a). Find the exact likelihood ratio statistic for testing the hypothesis $\mathrm{H}_0: a=2 b$ versus the general alternative, and give the approximate cutoff for large $n$, for a size- $\alpha$ test.

Now I know that $LR = \frac{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} L(Y)}{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} L(Y)}$

But I am not sure how to get the Maximum Likelihood estimates of a and b for the denominator.

My approach:
For the numerator I can show that the mle for b is $\hat{b_0} = \frac{n_1 + n_2}{3n}$, but for the denominator:

$L(\textbf{Y}) = a^{n_1} b^{n_2} (1 - a - b)^{n_3}$; where $n_1$ is the number of times y is between 0 and 1.

$$\log L(\textbf{Y}) = n_1 \log(a) + n_2 \log(b) + n_3 \log(1- a - b)$$

\begin{align}\partial l/\partial a &= \frac{n_1}{a} - \frac{ n_3}{1 - a - b} \\&= 0\\ \implies \hat{a} & = \frac{n_1(1-b)}{n_3 + n_1}\end{align}

\begin{align}\partial l/\partial b &= \frac{n_1}{b} - \frac{ n_3}{1 - a - b} \\&= 0\\ \implies \hat{b} &= \frac{n_2(1-a)}{n_3 + n_2}\end{align}

Now inserting $\hat{b}$ into the $b$ in $\hat{a}$ seems computationally time consuming to find the MLE of $a$ given that I also need to plug all these into the likelihood ratio statistic. Is there a quicker approach in finding the MLE?

Comment: I would do it exactly this way. It seems a lot of $n_1, n_2, n_3$, and this requires some concentration to solve. I would therefore use the abbreviations $c=\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_3}$ and $d=\frac{n_2}{n_2+n_3}$, then the equations look less intimidating and are easy to solve.